# Set-AuthenticodeSignature -TimestampServer with HTTPS?

Tags: powershell

In some of our environments we would like to use the TimestampServer option when signing so we don't have to worry about re-signing certificates. The issue we have is that in some environments we don't allow connections in or out on 80, only 443 and the TimestampServer parameter is expecting the url format to be http. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: To add, we're using our own internal CA if that makes a difference.

Comment: Did you tried `https` TimestampServer? Please [edit] the question and add an error message, if any.

Comment: I did but the error says it expects http for the URL format. I'm asking it it appears it's not supported but wanted to see if anyone else had ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the Timestamp Server protocol requires HTTP so HTTPS is not possible